# Angular 2 Uglify JS is not mangled

Tags: angular, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify, uglifyjs2

I tried to uglify my code so my variable- and function-names don't show up in production files.

As far as i see, Angular CLI (ng build -prod) is not doing the job. So i tried gulp-uglify. Still i see most of my functions with full names:

```
this.showHeader$=this.showHeaderSource.asObservable()
```

Dosn't work on uglify js demo, too: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular CLI is running Uglify but currently Uglify does not rename properties which may be a lot (most?) of Angular Code.

[Original answer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4498#issuecomment-278098917) by Angular CLI collaborator:

> We do run Uglify on your code, but unfortunately Uglify does not
>   rename properties, only function and variable names. A lot of your
>   methods will be properties and not renamed by Uglify. We're looking at
>   solutions but for the time being this is probably not going to change.